# mysql2 GemRequireError during server start

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I'm trying to get an old Ruby on Rails project up and running.  The project uses Ruby 1.9.3p484 and a bunch of gems, including mysql2, that are all successfully installed when I run `bundle install`.  However, when I run a `script/rails server` (like I said, old version of RoR), I get the following **mysql2** error:

> /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@iwny/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'mysql2'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)

and the stack trace:

```
/Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@iwny/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'mysql2'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@iwny/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@iwny/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@iwny/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@iwny/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@iwny/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@iwny/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from /Users/ryan/vagrant/source/adage/web/htdocs/iwny/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@iwny/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@iwny/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@iwny/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@iwny/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Like I said, `bundle install` worked just fine.  The Gemfile contains

```
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'
```

and versions for various software include the following:

- ruby 1.9.3p484
- rails 3.0.20
- rake 10.0.3
- rspec 2.12.2
- rake-compiler 10.5.0
- mysql: `Server version: 5.5.44-37.3-log Source distribution`

I can't really mess with too much core stuff as this is an established site/repo so I have to work with what I have here.

Comment: What is you Mysql version no?

Comment: 5.5.44 is the version

Comment: Please don't use images to show us errors or code or data. We need to be able to copy/paste those sort of things.

Comment: @theTinMan I copied and pasted the error as well............the image was more for supplementary information (the back trace below the error)..........

Comment: Yes, but not the back-trace, only the error. Back traces can be very useful.

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` or `gem install`? You mentioned in the starting that the `bundle install` was successful and later mentioned `gem install` was successful. Nevertheless, make sure that `bundle install` was successful and then run `bundle show mysql2` and see if `bundler` was able to find the mysql2 gem.

Comment: @Dharam my bad, changed it from `gem install` to `bundle install`.  I did a `bundle show mysql2` and it produced the gem's location: `/Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@iwny/gems/mysql2-0.2.18`